# Write in new line in rich text box. with vb

Tags: .net, vb.net, split, richtextbox

Hi guys i want to know how to write every word in a phrase in a new line 
in a richtextbox lets say the phrase is this
"Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited"

and the code i'm working with is this

```
Dim words As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim split As String() = words.Split(New [Char]() {" "c, CChar(vbTab)})

    For Each s As String In split
        If s.Trim() <> "" Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = (s)
        End If
    Next s
```

But with this one it only write the last word of the sentence.
And what i want is to write all the words each in a new line of the richtextbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `vbCrLf` constant:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", vbCrLf).Replace(vbTab, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: hi sir .. but if i have a tab button space its bigger than the normal space .. how can i replace it

Comment: Updated my answer to handle Tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim words As String = TextBox1.Text
words.Replace(" ", ControlChars.Lf)
RichTextBox1.Text = words
```

You just need to replace `" "` by `ControlChars.Lf` aka `New Line Character`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vbCrLf constant:

```
    For Each s As String In split
        If s.Trim() <> "" Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = (s) + vbCrLf
        End If
    Next s
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine except for one thing.  You are setting the RichTextBox to the string everytime, so it keeps overwriting.  You need to concatenate...

```
Dim words As String = TextBox1.Text
Dim split As String() = words.Split(New [Char]() {" "c, CChar(vbTab)})

For Each s As String In split
    If s.Trim() <> "" Then
        RichTextBox1.Text &= (s)
    End If
Next s
```

Note that addition of the "&" on the line that writes to the RTB.

Answer (score 0):

To add a new line, the best option is:

```
RichTextBoxResult.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
```